# Xpath (or) condition with node one of them

Tags: xpath

First, I'm familiar with `or` logic like this:

```
//*[@id='a' or @id='b']
```

But how to write the xpath if one of them having node (child, preceding, etc) like this:

```
//*[@id='a']//*[@id='aa'] or //*[@id='b']
```

The above return as invalid xpath.

I struggled to search on this forum but it was a bit difficult to find the right keywords.

How to write the correct xpath for the above issue?

Just simple snippet to get 2 result like the above explanation:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="aa"></div> --target
    <div id="aaa"></div>
    <div id="aaaa"></div>
</div>

<div id="b"></div> --target
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example XML input and which nodes you want to select?

Comment: I don't actually know what you want - it's hard to reverse-engineer your requirements from incorrect code -- but as a guess, perhaps you want the set union operator "|" in place of the boolean "or" operator?

Comment: @choroba question updated.

Answer (score 2):

`//*[@id='a']//*[@id='aa'] or //*[@id='b']` This XPath is not invalid - it returns boolean (true or false). But tools like Selenium might not support this syntax. I guess you need

```
//*[@id='a']//*[@id='aa'] | //*[@id='b']
```